# How to stop Azure Devops SQL Database Deployment Failing due to risk of data loss

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

When deploying a database project in Visual Studio to a Database, I have an option in the settings to 'block on possible data loss'. This setting is on by default. Is there a way to change this setting when doing deployments through Azure DevOps pipelines?

Comment: Read the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690504/facing-errors-while-sql-deployment-in-azure-devops-pipeline

Comment: Hi @Stephen Bowser UK Did the answer mentioned in above thread work for this case?